# Replicate exact CURL request using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, curl

I'm having a hard time trying to replicate a curl command using RestTemplate when uploading files to AWS S3.

Below curl works well, however when using rest template this is not working since internally it is changing some characters.

```
curl -v  \
    -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" \
    -H "Content-Length:5242880" \
    --upload-file /Users/fd/Downloads/xaa \
    'https://video-uploads-prod.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/ABCDEFQGfwwGyO2DKbQ/aws-userUploadedVideo?uploadId=qkpiUI.3zRrO6N0K2ThRJNEjeCJ90xKm5GvLyt92bGvn_CgHSRohbuVcPxubnHs5UhtIF2m.92umUHS1ScLxHT09ObrtYsDNKoPCYMtX.og5GH2jJFJzTwowHPR2NATP&partNumber=1&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200108T153659Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-length%3Bcontent-type%3Bhost&X-Amz-Expires=86399&X-Amz-Credential=ABCDEZHLABCWZ2MUPPBQ%2F20200108%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=abcde94e1a87d2169ce000d5b1275d422c66360136e0488d9714db4f12199740'
```

The curl output is:

```
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I'm using java 8 with Spring Boot 1.5.6. The java code I used is:

```
byte[] media = //video in mp4//;
String uploadUrl = "https://video-uploads-prod.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/ABCDEFQGfwwGyO2DKbQ/aws-userUploadedVideo?uploadId=qkpiUI.3zRrO6A0B2ThRCDEjeCJ90xKm5GvLyt92bGvn_CgHSRohbuVcPxubnHs5UhtIF2m.92umUHS1ScLxHT09ObrtYsDNKoPCYMtX.og5GH2jJFJzTwowHPR2NATP&partNumber=1&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200108T153659Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-length%3Bcontent-type%3Bhost&X-Amz-Expires=86399&X-Amz-Credential=ABCDEZHLABCWZ2MUPPBQ%2F20200108%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=abcde94e1a87d2169ce000d5b1275d422c66360136e0488d9714db4f12199740";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
headers.set("Content-Length", "5242880");

HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity<>(media, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> respEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uploadUrl, PUT, entity, String.class);
```

The response I get is that the signature does not match:

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>ABCDEFQGfwwGyO2DKbQ</AWSAccessKeyId>...
```

I have tried multiple approaches with `restTemplate.exchange`, like using `UriComponentsBuilder` instead of plain `url` string, using URI, using decoded `url` string but found no way to call a literal url and avoiding RestTemplate to modify the url.

I know I can call `curl` command from Java, but I want to know **how to call a literal url using RestTemplate to replicate the exact behavior as curl and avoid RestTemplate to modify it**. Is this possible or I cannot use RestTemplate for this purpose?

Comment: Deleted. So `Java` is complaining that the key correct key does not work? Can you post what differences there are (if any).

Comment: @l'L'l the problem is that `RestTemplate.exchange` internally modifies the `url`, it performs an internal encoding that borks the url, while curl uses as it is, hence the error of different signature